# On a ChromeOS device how do I grant serial port permissions?

Tags: serial-port, google-chrome-os, chromebox

I am working on a kiosk application and I need to be able to grant permissions to access the Web Serial API without any user interaction.  This is on a ChromeBox that is managed through the Google console (https://admin.google.com) and I have added permissions for my device in both the "user & browser" and the "Managed guest".

I am still only able to access the serial ports through a user interaction, such as a click event.

[Google admin console serial permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPzCu.png)

The Google documentation for these settings state that:

> Available on ChromeOS devices and Chrome browser for Windows, Mac, and Linux.
> You can specify a list of sites that can connect to serial devices with specific vendor and product IDs. Access to these devices is automatically allowed for the corresponding web apps on the client side.

I am expecting to be able to get the available ports, open, read and write to the serial port when a user is not present to interact with the device.

Comment: hi, did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: Only when the ChromeOS device is in managed, kiosk mode, and no debugger is attached.  I had to create a route to the server to post console traffic to so that I could debug my application.